# How to form a socket url in django channels?

Tags: django, django-views, django-channels

How to form a socket url in django channels? I am able to use sockets in my templates, but I want to test it with postman. Instead of using it in javascript template, I want to create a backend API.

The URL router in routing.py consists of

```
path('chat/<room_id>/', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
```

I am accessing this URL`ws://127.0.0.1:8000/public_chat/1` in postman, but it says Access denied.

Also, which address(127.0.0.1:8000) should I use? The one for Django Application or the redis one used for messages ?